# Rake Task Rails Aborted: Connection Refused 10061

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rake aborted: could possibly anybody tell me what was going wrong here? maybe with the rakefile.. ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt5Kv.png

Comment: Port 5432 appears to be the default port for Postgresql. It’s looking for it on localhost, so it seems to expect a Postgres database to be running on your computer, and it’s not finding it. I’d guess you just need to start Postgres.

Comment: thank you. that's the solution

Comment: You’re very welcome!